# An ImplicitRegion with a boundary which is an Interpolated Function is not a ConstantRegion

Tags: regions, finite-element-method, mesh

I create an ImplicitRegion from a box-shaped region with one face replaced by a function h[x,y]. If h[x,y] is a "normal" function, e.g.

```
h[x_,y_]:=y/(1+x^2)
solnRegn = ImplicitRegion[{z > h[x,y]},{{x, -60, 700}, {y, -60, 700}, {z, 110, 240}}];
```

then my region is a ConstantRegion. If it is created from an Interpolation, e.g.

```
data = {{539, 700, 135}, {586, 700, 135}, {413, 700, 113}, {277, 700, 
110}, {441, 700, 120}, {154, 700, 115}, {0, 700, 121}, {539, 640, 
135}, {586, 640, 135}, {413, 640, 113}, {277, 640, 110}, {441, 
640, 120}, {154, 640, 115}, {0, 640, 121}, {0, 103, 170}, {0, 257,
 155}, {0, 219, 160}, {0, 77, 200}, {0, 395, 133}, {0, 494, 
128}, {0, 0, 235}, {0, -60, 235}, {-60, 700, 121}, {-60, 640, 
121}, {-60, 103, 170}, {-60, 257, 155}, {-60, 219, 160}, {-60, 77,
 200}, {-60, 395, 133}, {-60, 494, 128}, {-60, 0, 235}, {413, 0, 
225}, {280, 0, 235}, {50, 0, 230}, {573, 0, 225}, {90, 0, 
235}, {640, 0, 215}, {700, 0, 215}, {-60, -60, 235}, {413, -60, 
225}, {280, -60, 235}, {50, -60, 230}, {573, -60, 225}, {90, -60, 
235}, {640, -60, 215}, {640, 345, 200}, {640, 193, 224}, {640, 
461, 135}, {640, 393, 160}, {640, 640, 125}, {640, 700, 
125}, {700, -60, 215}, {700, 345, 200}, {700, 193, 224}, {700, 
461, 135}, {700, 393, 160}, {700, 640, 125}, {700, 700, 
125}, {436, 451, 125}, {252, 442, 125}, {252, 336, 125}, {336, 
336, 125}, {220, 444, 135}, {196, 353, 135}, {347, 47, 225}, {151,
 402, 175}, {90, 543, 120}, {518, 543, 130}, {566, 612, 
165}, {583, 565, 165}, {169, 274, 150}, {420, 274, 150}, {169, 
366, 150}, {409, 75, 220}, {236, 104, 185}, {205, 249, 140}, {472,
 168, 175}, {426, 168, 175}, {426, 381, 138}, {138, 168, 
215}, {259, 196, 140}, {473, 257, 205}, {259, 257, 130}, {473, 
196, 175}, {299, 99, 200}, {400, 351, 140}, {299, 351, 121}, {400,
 99, 195}, {260, 91, 200}, {369, 91, 185}, {527, 601, 125}, {149, 
601, 115}, {527, 403, 205}, {320, 141, 160}, {537, 454, 
190}, {320, 454, 116}, {537, 141, 225}, {32, 193, 160}, {32, 345, 
142}, {112, 270, 200}, {597, 359, 205}, {112, 359, 195}, {597, 
270, 220}, {128, 89, 210}, {468, 397, 160}, {128, 397, 175}, {468,
 89, 222}, {151, 327, 150}, {151, 454, 145}, {450, 327, 
205}, {490, 436, 150}, {159, 436, 163}, {490, 116, 220}, {158, 81,
 235}, {579, 167, 229}, {224, 475, 145}, {286, 516, 130}, {224, 
516, 130}, {286, 475, 125}, {70, 166, 165}, {179, 446, 160}, {481,
 586, 130}, {432, 586, 130}, {481, 534, 130}, {464, 551, 
136}, {529, 374, 210}, {432, 534, 130}, {45, 147, 160}, {68, 219, 
165}, {361, 619, 110}, {361, 494, 114}, {68, 395, 140}, {59, 60, 
180}, {98, 326, 193}, {59, 326, 155}, {98, 60, 200}, {589, 310, 
215}, {589, 588, 160}, {558, 572, 160}, {503, 572, 127}, {558, 
398, 205}, {325, 205, 135}, {325, 96, 182}, {255, 74, 220}, {105, 
188, 190}, {155, 188, 201}, {82, 70, 180}, {486, 316, 215}, {525, 
316, 217}, {486, 388, 190}, {410, 298, 150}, {513, 257, 
220}, {513, 103, 225}, {170, 133, 223}, {198, 133, 210}, {519, 
461, 161}, {590, 506, 167}, {519, 506, 136}, {590, 461, 
180}, {434, 202, 150}, {150, 268, 172}, {163, 217, 164}, {347, 
123, 160}, {387, 141, 155}, {411, 186, 155}, {411, 247, 
150}, {446, 147, 205}, {446, 176, 165}, {95, 115, 175}, {95, 157, 
175}, {271, 126, 160}, {377, 191, 140}, {377, 257, 140}, {328, 
267, 130}, {232, 158, 158}, {208, 190, 159}, {247, 127, 
160}, {211, 45, 235}, {557, 545, 160}, {557, 505, 160}, {125, 207,
 208}, {278, 71, 225}, {436, 242, 160}};
data = 1. data;(*Fix precision*)
h = 
 Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
Print["Test ", h[2, 3]];
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
solnRegn = 
  ImplicitRegion[{z > h[x, y]}, {{x, -60, 700}, {y, -60, 700}, {z, 
     110, 240}}];
ConstantRegionQ[solnRegn]
ToBoundaryMesh[solnRegn]["Wireframe"]
```

then ConstantRegionQ returns "False":

[image]

although, as can be seen, the ToBoundaryMesh function does in fact work. But why is ConstantRegionQ False? Something wrong with my interpolation?

It is somewhat surprising (but perfectly fine, of course) that both ToBoundaryMesh and ToElementMesh work with this, since ConstantRegionQ is False and their documentation says that they require ConstantRegionQ=True.

Comment: Works just fine for me. If you make a post make sure that you have included all information to reproduce the issue you are seeing. What is `data`, `xMn` etc.

Comment: I have edited the question to be more explicit about the input variables/data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works just fine for me:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
data = Flatten[Table[{{x, y}, LCM[x, y]}, {x, 4}, {y, 4}], 1];
if = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
solnRegn = 
  ImplicitRegion[{z > if[x, y]}, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}}];
ConstantRegionQ[solnRegn]
ToBoundaryMesh[solnRegn]["Wireframe"]

(* False *)
```

[image]

Comment: When I paste exactly your code (above) into my notebook, ConstantRegionQ[solnRegn] returns False. I am using MMA 12.0.0 on Mac.

Comment: I am not sure if the `False` that is returned from `ConstantRegionQ` is correct. The reason that the ref pages have this mention of ConstantRegionQ is that a region like `Disk[{0,0},variableR]` can not be discretized if `variableR` is not defined. In any case `ToElementMesh` happily performs the discretization which is good.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I guess it is a bug in ConstantRegionQ then, since regions created thus are manifestly ConstantRegions. I agree that it is good that the ToElementMesh works anyway.

Comment: I forwarded the question about `ConstantRegionQ` in house and we'll see what people have to say.

Comment: @PaulHarrison, sorry forgot to @ you.

Comment: @PaulHarrison I filed the ConstantRegionQ issue as a bug.

Comment: Thanks, as ever, for your help!

Answer (score 2):

One workaround is to define a function that's explicitly numeric:

```
data = Flatten[Table[{{x, y}, LCM[x, y]}, {x, 4}, {y, 4}], 1];
if = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1];

SetAttributes[g, NumericFunction];
g[x_?NumericQ, y_] := if[x, y]

reg = ImplicitRegion[z > g[x, y], {{x, 1, 4}, {y, 1, 4}, {z, 1, 4}}];

ConstantRegionQ[reg]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Thanks Chip, that looks a promising way forward. I will try it.

Comment: As a work-around, your suggestion works, Chip, thanks. It of course does not explain why ToElementMesh works for my Interpolated function without the workaround, but ToBoundaryMesh does not.

Comment: Correction, ToBoundaryMesh also works, even though ConstantRegionQ is False for the original input.